# Assembly Code Array or regular line of code?

Tags: c, assembly, att

I have a rather simple assemble code, but it is making me second guess myself.

```
fn:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    sall    $2, %eax
    addl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

So what I have as a function is

```
int main(int x, int y)
{
    x = 4*y + x;
    return x;
}
```

but I thought this looks similar to an array index (saw a similar post but still not sure).
I'm not completely sure if this block of code is correct.

Comment: You've overlooked the `movl (%eax), %eax` line. The return value is not the result of 4*y+x, but the DWORD at that location. By the way, when using indexed array with integers access in C, the 4 multiplier is implicit.

Comment: can you give me a little more direction on what the `movl (%eax), %eax` segment does in line of code?

Comment: Ah with some more thinking, I got it... I think! It was just a very simple array!

Comment: It loads into EAX (which is ultimately the return value) the value at the address which is stored in EAX initially. The initial value of EAX is lost.

Comment: in other words the function should have been `x[y]`?